# Change log level of messages from logger on propagation

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

I have a module which uses a Logger object.

```
logger = logging.getLogger('module')
logger.error("Error Message")
```

I am importing the module for a script with a root logger and handler configured to write to a file. How do I make it so that all error and above messages automatically have their level changed to INFO when it's propagated to the parent logger?

Comment: I propose that you just not do it, it's easier: zero lines of code, zero surprise, zero bug introduced, zero millisecond added. Errors are errors, not info, you may just want to downgrade them.

Comment: The errors thrown up by these are caught and handled. It's just that the module writes it's own error logs.